# AdMob SDK complie failed under iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ios7.1, arm64

- Xcode 5.1 (5B130a)
- iOS 7.1
- using CocoaPods

  ```
  pod 'Google-AdMob-Ads-SDK'
  ```

compile failed with log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check to make sure that the GAD library has been added in xcode linked frameworks and libraries.

The second thing to look at is the Storekit framework. These classes that are giving you an error are from the storekit. Check to ensure that it's added to your project

Answer (score 2):

try to add CoreTelephony and CoreText in framework of project.